# Deliver apk android install to iframe the website

Tags: android, apk

I want to make an application for my website but I don't want it to be really an application. I want to deliver and apk that can be installed on android device and just I frames the website and show the site in responsive mode. Is it easy to do that or any online tool for that!?

Comment: yeah, you can just slap a webview of your website into a screen and that's it. It should take 5 or so lines

Comment: Is there any tutorial or ready snippet or tool for it because I am php developer and have no experience of  android

Comment: do you have an experience with android studio?

Comment: Nope unfortionatly

Comment: what is your email? If you want, send me your app logo that you want and website link. I can send you .apk app if you want. My email is graspery@gmail.com

Comment: ok sure thank i will send it to you and you can make this as an answer and i will accep it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is your email? If you want, send me your app logo that you want and website link. I can send you .apk app if you want. My email is graspery@gmail.com